# NTFS Partitions mounted as read-only on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: partitioning, 19.10, ntfs, read-only

It's my first time installing Ubuntu. I deleted Windows and installed Ubuntu 19.10 but now my NTFS Partitions are mounted as `read-only` even when I change it to `read-write` it turns back time after time. What do I need to do?
I am afraid to do any action that may lead me to lose data.

edit 1 : 
as I used ( /etc/fstab ) lines it gave me permission denied every time so I used mount and checked the long list , it clearly say Read only indeed. sir : Jos ///
I am new to ubuntu thank u for checking the post and advice . sir : oldfred

Comment: Try turning windows fast boot off. From control panel > power options> change what power buttons do.

Comment: ah , sry I should edit my Q , there is no longer windows I only have ubuntu installed on my lap

Comment: Do you have lines in `/etc/fstab` describing these partitions? If so, do they include the `rw` option?

Comment: If you do not have Windows, you really should not use NTFS. Have at least a Windows repair/recovery drive. NTFS requires maintenance, including chkdsk & defrag that you cannot run from Linux.

Comment: You can force `rw` mode, check this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236145/24383